# laravel update record when it's not empty?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have a code like this:

```
public function createOrGetUser(Provider $provider)
{
    $providerUser = $provider->user();
    $providerName = class_basename($provider);
    $token = $providerUser->token;
    $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider($providerName)
        ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
        ->first();
    if ($account) {
        return $account->user;
    }else{
        $account = new SocialAccount([
            'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            'provider' => $providerName
        ]);
        $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
        if($user->first()) {
        if($providerName == "FacebookProvider") {
            $user->facebook_token = $token;
        }elseif($providerName == "TwitterProvider") {
            $user->twitter_token = $token;
        }else{
            $user->google_token = $token;
            }
        $user->save();
        }
        if (!$user) {
            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                'avatar' => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
            ]);
        }
        $account->user()->associate($user);
        $account->save();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

The only problem with that is it never runs the check for $providerName == "facebookprovider" etc and update the token for that user. Is there any particular reason for why this is happening?

Comment: With `$user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();`, you already get one object. Why, in the next line, do you reuse `first()`?

Comment: why use this `if($user->first())` it is better if you use `if(!empty($user))`

Comment: I tried if(!empty($user)) and it didn't work

Comment: try to dump your `$user` before if statement

Answer (score 0):

Found on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results):

> If you just need to retrieve a single row from the database table, you
>   may use the first method. This method will return a single **StdClass**
>   **object**

You get stdClass object when you called `first()` the first time. The second one will probably never be true, because this class has not this method.

It could work if you change `if ($user->first())` by `if ($user)`.